# Getting file from POST to upload to Parse with Slim framework

Tags: php, forms, parse-platform, slim

I'm currently trying to upload a file to Parse following the posting of a form with the Slim framework. For some reason I get the file name, but can't actually get the file with my current setup. I've also tried looking for the `$_FILES` array, but nothing is coming across. Is there something I'm missing? Here's my current route:

```
$app->group('/settings', function () use ($app) {
    $app->post('/update(/:settingsId)', function ($settingsId = null) use ($app) {
        $query = new ParseQuery("Settings");
        // Get a specific object:
        $settings = $query->get($settingsId);

        // Set values:
        $settings->set("appName", $app->request->post('appName'));
        $settings->set("directorName", $app->request->post('directorName'));
        $settings->set("mkUsername", $app->request->post('mkUsername'));
        $settings->set("mkPassword", $app->request->post('mkPassword'));

        error_log(print_r($_FILES, true));

        // see if we have a file
        if ($app->request->post('appBackgroundImage')) {
            // save file to Parse
            $appBackgroundImage = ParseFile::createFromData(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]), $app->request->post('appBackgroundImage'));
            $appBackgroundImage->save();

            $settings->set("appBackgroundImage", $appBackgroundImage);
        }

        try {
            $settings->save();
            $app->redirect('/settings');
        } catch (ParseException $ex) {
            $app->redirect('/settings/' . $ex->getCode());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is entirely the correct way to accomplish this, but this is how I got it to work. If someone has a better idea, I'd be all ears...

I added this to my JS so it actually posts the form via AJAX and pushes the file along with the normal form contents as well.

```
// File Uploader
        var form = document.getElementById('settings-form');
        form.onsubmit = function() {
          var formData = new FormData(form);

          formData.append('appBackgroundImage', file);

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          // Add any event handlers here...
          xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
          xhr.send(formData);

          return false; // To avoid actual submission of the form
        }
```